# Prove that there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that $\left(\dfrac{p}{5} \right) = 1$

Tags: number-theory

> Let $\left(\dfrac{a}{p}\right)$ denote the Legendre symbol. Prove that there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that $\left(\dfrac{p}{5} \right) = 1$.

Since there are infinitely many primes there must be infinitely many primes $p$ such that  $\left(\dfrac{p}{5} \right) = -1,0,$ or $1$. How do we prove that $1$ is achieved infinitely many times?

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:**
Assume by contradiction that primes of the form $5k+1$ are finite, $p_1,\ldots,p_m$,
 then consider
$$ \Phi_5(p_1\cdot p_2\cdot\ldots\cdot p_m+1) \tag{1} $$
where $\Phi_5(x)=x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$.

By Lagrange's theorem, every prime factor of $(1)$ has to be $\equiv 1\pmod{5}$, but $p_1,\ldots,p_m$ do not divide $(1)$.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: @user19405892: have a look at section 8.5 www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/algebra/notes/08.pdf

Comment: @user19405892: the trick is just that any prime factor of $\Phi_5(m)$ has to be $\equiv 1\pmod{5}$ by Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: (the argument is that $\Phi_5(k)$ is not divisible by any of the $p_i$, and if a prime $p | \Phi_5(k)$ then $p | k^5-1$, and by Fermat $k^{p-1} \equiv 1 \bmod 5$ hence $p \equiv 1 \bmod 5$)

Answer (score 2):

The  method that requires little extra machinery is to assume there is a finite list, let $P$ be the product of all of them, then take
$$ N = 20 P^2 -1.   $$
Well, $N$ is not divisible by $2,5$ or by any of the primes dividing $P.$ Quadratic residues show that $N$ is not divisible by any prime $q$ with $(q|5) = -1,$ since $5 \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $(q|5) = (5|q).$ However, either $N$ is itself prime or it is divisible by some prime, either way there is a new prime $p|N$ with $(p|5)=1.$

Comment: Why do you think of it as cheap? I find this is a pretty standard / student friendly approach to the problem.

Comment: @Imago Thank you. Sometimes I write low budget. On the whole, small machinery requirement. It is not evident here, but I typically have very quick answers for algebraic number theory of quadratic fields, where I use binary quadratic forms. Examples would include class number for a given discriminant, where they are writing ideals with the Minkowski bounds and getting lost, and I have an immediate list of distinct forms/classes.

Comment: @Imago recommend book https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mythago_Wood  wonderful